# How to set environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH through build.gradle to generate protobuf code

Tags: build.gradle, protocol-buffers, grpc, protoc, protobuf-java

1. I am using protobuf gradle plugin in my build.gradle file to
   generate grpc and reactor gprc java code.
2. Due to the security constraints, I cannot use the plugin directly
   from the maven central. I have to download those plugins and provide
   the local path in my gradle file.
3. Unfortunately, while setting things locally, it seems that the
   protoc compiler looks for LD_LIBRARY_PATH which we need to provide
   explicitly.

**Is there a way to set this path in gradle file?**

Below is how I am using protobuf plugin

```
apply plugin: "com.google.protobuf"

protobuf {
    protoc {
        path = "Local protoc path"
    }
    plugins {
        grpc {
            path = "Local Protoc gen grpc path"
        }
        reactor {
            path = "Local salesforce reactor grpc path
        }
    }
    generateProtoTasks {
        ofSourceSet("main")*.plugins {
            grpc {}
            reactor {}
        }
    }
}
```

Running above file gives below error

> "error while loading shared libraries: libprotoc.so.15: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

Looking for this error online shows that I need to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

Answer (score 0):

The protoc version on [Maven Central](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/protobuf/protoc/3.9.1/) is statically linked with libprotoc, so LB_LIBRARY_PATH would not be necessary. Use it instead. Note that the files must have a file extension, so they use the `.exe` file extension even on Linux. You can similarly download the [grpc protoc plugin](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1oSvEm1gHON5w2yzvjCg3zO_F5hl_UWRAzPdvx7J9BJM/edit#heading=h.ex4c9b2861nw).